# Blender via ssh?

Tags: linux

I was just wondering if it is even remotely possible to setup a Blender installation on a server (probably Linux based); then, on another computer SSH into the server and use Blender.

I believe if this were possible, it would probably run terribly, but I was just wondering how possible this actually is.

I know that simple GUI Java applications can be run in this way by using something like XMing on the local computer. Can the same sort of principle apply here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's definitely possible! If you have X11 forwarding set up on your SSH client and server, running Blender over the SSH connection should *just work* (I have tried it!). I am thinking of *nix-to-*nix here, but, on Windows, [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) can be [configured to use Xming](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.shtml) for X11 forwarding as well.

That said, as you suspect, the performance will be terrible unless you are using a fast LAN connection. Here is what I recommend doing.

- Set up both an SSH and a localhost VNC server on the computer on
  which you want to run Blender (the server).
- Using SSH, forward the port that the VNC server is using from the server to the client.
- Now connect a VNC viewer, running on the client, to the port of the VNC server that you just forwarded to the client.

Some VNC servers and clients (like [TigerVNC](http://tigervnc.org/)) support [JPEG compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG), so very usable framerates can be achieved with sub-optimal connections. I have been able to use Blender in the above configuration over a 10 megabit Internet connection without major problems. Another big advantage of using VNC over SSH is that applications running in the VNC server stay running even when a client is not connected (or even if a client is forcefully disconnected). Conversely, with SSH and X11 forwarding, the SSH connection must be maintained for as long as the application is used.

I think I should also mention [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/). From its website,

> **x11vnc** allows one to view remotely and interact with real X displays (i.e. a display corresponding to a physical monitor, keyboard, and mouse) with any VNC viewer.

As such, it allows you to run Blender with hardware-accelerated OpenGL and *still* access it via VNC.

Comment: What do you think about a raspberry pi being the client? Also, is TigerVNC available on major linux distros (like fedora 20)

Comment: In theory it would work with the Raspberry Pi, although I would be concerned about the Pi being too slow at uncompressing and displaying the image to really be able to use Blender effectively. TigerVNC appears to be [available in Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/tigervnc).

Comment: Fixed link for Fedora package (the old one is a 404 now): https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/tigervnc/

Answer (score 5):

As Catlover2 points out it can be done but preferably over a fast local network.

Another option is to run blender locally to create the scene and then run blender remotely over ssh to do the rendering without using any gui elements.

```
blender -b myblendfile.blend -f
```

You could also setup any number of remote machines that automatically startup as slaves to do rendering through Network Render.

Comment: Thanks @sambler. Do you know what the status might be for Blender 2.80? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144083/how-to-get-blender-2-80-to-render-through-an-ssh-connection-minimal-working-ex